# Is there any performance difference between declaring a variable and using it directly in method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

If I am going to call a function, lets say a print function like:

```rb
def print(message)
   //... 
end
```

What's the difference between:

```rb
print("Message")
```

and

```
message = "Message"
print(message)
```

Im curious since ruby is an interpreted language, then I don't know if this has consequences in memory management or something else.

Comment: What makes you say "Ruby is not compiled"? *Every single currently existing Ruby implementation* has at least one compiler. Some even have more than one, e.g. YARV has two.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Ruby is widely considered an interpreted language, Ruby is partially compiled in most common implementations of the language. The standard interpreter (YARV) compiles your source code into bytecode first, and then interprets that bytecode. (If you'd like to go more in-depth on this topic, I can highly recommend [Ruby under a Microscope](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope)).

You can use `RubyVM::InstructionSequence` to see the bytecode generated for particular Ruby code. Let's compare the bytecode for your two examples:

```
irb(main):002:0> puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("print('Message')").dis
asm

== disasm: #<ISeq:<compiled>@<compiled>:1 (1,0)-(1,16)> (catch: FALSE)
0000 putself                                                          (   1)[Li]
0001 putstring                    "Message"
0003 opt_send_without_block       <callinfo!mid:print, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0006 leave
=> nil


irb(main):003:0> puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("message = 'Message'; print(message)").disasm
== disasm: #<ISeq:<compiled>@<compiled>:1 (1,0)-(1,35)> (catch: FALSE)
local table (size: 1, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1, kw: -1@-1, kwrest: -1])
[ 1] message@0
0000 putstring                    "Message"                           (   1)[Li]
0002 setlocal_WC_0                message@0
0004 putself
0005 getlocal_WC_0                message@0
0007 opt_send_without_block       <callinfo!mid:print, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0010 leave
=> nil
```

As we can see here, `print('Message')` has fewer bytecode instructions, so will likely be *very slightly* faster (not enough faster to sacrifice clarity when writing code). Also, `print('Message')` doesn't use any local variables, so no local variable table is required for that snippet.

Your `message = 'Message'; print(message)` example has more bytecode instructions, because it needs to set and get the local variable, and subsequently also requires a local variable table (shown as `local table (size: 1, ...)`). This means it'll take up a little bit more memory.

Despite two different approaches, you're still creating the same object overall - a string `'Message'`. Because of that, there's little effect on the garbage collector, as we can see from the value of `GC.stat`: (a.rb does not use a local and b.rb does)

```
$ ruby a.rb                                                                                                        
Message{:count=>12, :heap_allocated_pages=>51, :heap_sorted_length=>62, :heap_allocatable_pages=>11, :heap_available_slots=>20791, :heap_live_slots=>20530, :heap_free_slots=>261, :heap_final_slots=>0, :heap_marked_slots=>15224, :heap_eden_pages=>51, :heap_tomb_pages=>0, :total_allocated_pages=>51, :total_freed_pages=>0, :total_allocated_objects=>68286, :total_freed_objects=>47756, :malloc_increase_bytes=>374152, :malloc_increase_bytes_limit=>16777216, :minor_gc_count=>9, :major_gc_count=>3, :remembered_wb_unprotected_objects=>213, :remembered_wb_unprotected_objects_limit=>424, :old_objects=>14957, :old_objects_limit=>29920, :oldmalloc_increase_bytes=>431824, :oldmalloc_increase_bytes_limit=>16777216}%

$ ruby b.rb                                                                                                        
Message{:count=>12, :heap_allocated_pages=>51, :heap_sorted_length=>62, :heap_allocatable_pages=>11, :heap_available_slots=>20785, :heap_live_slots=>20518, :heap_free_slots=>267, :heap_final_slots=>0, :heap_marked_slots=>15209, :heap_eden_pages=>51, :heap_tomb_pages=>0, :total_allocated_pages=>51, :total_freed_pages=>0, :total_allocated_objects=>68288, :total_freed_objects=>47770, :malloc_increase_bytes=>374488, :malloc_increase_bytes_limit=>16777216, :minor_gc_count=>9, :major_gc_count=>3, :remembered_wb_unprotected_objects=>213, :remembered_wb_unprotected_objects_limit=>424, :old_objects=>14956, :old_objects_limit=>29918, :oldmalloc_increase_bytes=>434104, :oldmalloc_increase_bytes_limit=>16777216}
```

The `:count` key shows the number of times the garbage collector has run, and it's the same for both of your examples, so it doesn't really affect garbage collection.

Comment: Actually, current versions of YARV, 1) compile Ruby to YARV byte code, then 2) compile (some of) the YARV byte code to C, and then 3) call GCC to compile the generated C to native machine code. So, current versions of YARV contain two compilers themselves and call out to a third one, to compile the code up to three times.

Comment: That's true, I'd forgotten that a JIT had been added recently!

Comment: I'm surprised that the GC even runs at all. For such a simple snippet of code that immediately exits again, I would have expected that the GC never runs in the first place and the implementation just terminates the process and lets the operating system clean up any resources, including memory. I'm guessing that those results are heavily distorted by loading RubyGems, `did_you_mean`, IRb, and all the other stuff.